# Reliable way of sending email of a file containing HTML code

Tags: python, html-email

I have a HTML code in a text file `emailtext.txt` @ http://pastie.org/8276028 ,currently I am using the following code to send an email(via outlook) in HTML format but the formatting seems messed up sometimes... can someone provide inputs on how to send this email in a reliable way?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE

    def email (body,subject,to=None):
          msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
          msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=UTF8"
          msg["From"] = "userid@qualcomm.com"
          if to!=None:
              to=to.strip()
              msg["To"] = to
          else:
              msg["To"] = "userid2@company.com"
          msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
          p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-f" + msg["From"]], stdin=PIPE)
          p.communicate(msg.as_string())
          print "Done"


    def main ():

        with open('emailtext.txt', 'r') as f:
            body = f.read()

        Subject ="test email"
        email(body, Subject, "userid3@company.com")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by reliable ?

Comment: Have you tried using `smtplib.SMTP` instead of calling sendmail directly?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - formatting is getting messed up sometimes,so am wondering if there is a better way to send the email of a text file containing HTML code

Comment: @user2639990 Are you sure it's not just your HTML that's messed up?

Comment: @korylprince - please provide inputs on how to use smtplib.SMTP?

Comment: @user2639990 read http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

Comment: @korylprince - can you suggest how to use smtplib ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using smtplib:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
s = SMTP('localhost',25)
s.sendmail('Me <me@example.com>', ['You <you@example.com>'],msg=msg.as_string())
```

If that doesn't work then your HTML is probably bad.